# How do I avoid making a function call twice?

Tags: haskell

Haskell newbie question: Is there a technique to be more efficient and avoid the call on tail originalList twice

```
func1 originalList =
    func2 (doSomething (tail originalList)) (doSomethingDifferent (tail originalList))

doSomething listA =
....

doSomethingDifferent listB =
....

func2 listA listB =
....
```

Comment: please explain bit more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In an *imperative programming* language, you call the function once, and store it into a variable.

In a functional programming language like Haskell, you use a `where` or `let` clause and thus use a variable as well:

```
func1 originalList = func2 (doSomething t) (doSomethingDifferent t)
    where t = tail originalList
```

So here you will construct an expression, and the arguments of `doSomething` and `doSomethingDifferent` will *refer* to the same expression tree. Now since Haskell works *lazily* `tail originalList` will *not* be evaluated immediately.

But if it is (partially) evaluated (for instance when evaluating the first operand of the `func2` call), then that work is *not* redone when evaluating the expression tree through another way (for instance the second argument). Now in case of a `tail` there is not much work anyway. But in case it was a more complex function, it would pay off more.

Note that - like [@amalloy says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44719944/how-do-i-avoid-making-a-function-call-twice/44720025?noredirect=1#comment76439549_44720025) - in case of a `tail` function, you do not have to use a where clause: simple pattern matching will suffice:

```
func1 (_:t) = func2 (doSomething t) (doSomethingDifferent t)
```

Note that the two are not fully equivalent: since now there is a constraint that the line will only *fire* if you have a list with at least one element. It could be possible that `func2` simply ignores both arguments, such that obtaining the tail is not necessary (although that is unlikely here).

Comment: It would be better still to pattern-match `originalList` when binding it, so that this `where` is not needed at all, and you don't have to call the dangerous function `tail`.

Comment: @amalloy: yes, but here I considered `tail` to be a *blackbox* function (since it should be applicable to any kind of function).

Comment: Indeed your advice is good for a general function `f`, but I think it is worth noting, either as a comment or as part of the answer, that it is bad advice for the specific function `tail`, since that is the one that was asked about.